# when is double parenthesis construct for conditional statements useful?

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements

I've been reading the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) trying to learn more about what is considered best practice and came across this way of constructing conditionals:

```
#condition?result-if-true:result-if-false

(( var0 = var1<98?9:21 ))
#                ^ ^

# if [ "$var1" -lt 98 ]
# then
#   var0=9
# else
#   var0=21
# fi
```

It looks cool but is there an advantage to this outside of how compact it is?

Comment: They're exactly equivalent. Use whatever seems clearest to you.

Comment: BTW, the ABS is generally considered a very poor reference choice -- it's infamous in some circles for showcasing bad practices (which is to say, ABS:bash::W3Schools:JavaScript). Consider the [bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) or the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) instead.

Comment: By the way, that's called the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), and it exists in many languages.  Regardless of the language, I try to only use the ternary operator when the terms are very short, otherwise it can be harder to read than `if...else` statements.

Comment: FYI, the [ `cond` ] style originates from Bourne Shell.  Korn Shell and Bash introduced the [[ `cond` ]]  for files and strings and (( `cond` )) for arithmetic expressions which are an improvement to [ `cond` ] which is problematic unless you double quote your arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may look cool in geeky eyes, but it's difficult to read. There is no advantage to this. So stick to if-then-else or put a lot of comments on it just like you did in your question.

Comment: Only geeks read bash scripts. The rest of the world prefers Wuthering Heights.